# Storing Images in Rails API and passing it to React App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, image, api

I have a portfolio website that I am building right now using Rails API and React JS, and I would like to store images of my projects (more than 1 image for 1 project) and display it on my React JS app.

I was wondering what is the best practice to store images and display them? When using only Rails, I would upload my pictures to Cloudinary and use the link from cloudinary and seed it inside my Rails App, then display it in my view using a cl image tag. But combining it with React, I am not sure if this is the best practice.

If for instance, I go to this website: 
http://austinmayer.co/work/nike 
https://evagher.com/en/album/mittu
The images are stored in a local folder somewhere; I would like to achieve the same but I don't know how to program it under the hood.

Appreciate any insights. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I would upload the image straight from the client to cloudinary or your cloud platform of choice and then just send the URL of the uploaded file to Rails so that it updates/creates the model in the database.

Comment: You can also proxy the upload through your rails server as well but then you have to either deal with the issues of base64 encoding/decoding the file so that it can be sent through JSON or make your API accept multipart form submissions and it also ties up web threads on your server just piping data through it.